# What is handy way to modify the private class data members without writing explicit setters? Are templates useful?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, private, datamember

I have a class with data members.

```
class Sph
{
public:
    Sph( float radius , float segments , const Shader& shader );
    Sph(const Sph& geometry);
    Sph& operator = (const Sph& geometry);
    ~Sph();
    void init();
    void CleanUp();
    void draw();
    void CreateUI(QFormLayout* layout);
    std::vector< Sum_Vertices > GetVertices();

private:
    float Radius,Segments;
    bool isInited;
    unsigned int m_VAO, m_VBO , m_IBO;
    int iNumsToDraw;
    bool isChanged;
    Shader shader;
    int indexCount;
};
```

in order to change the data of the class I have to write individual methods.

```
void SetRadius( float radius )
{
   this->Radius = radius;
}
```

Is it possible to write a templated function which can change different data members of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variables are different by names, the `template` may not help here.

---

This is a classic case, where you can use macros to your advantage & ease.

**Definition**:

```
#define GET_SET(X) X; \ 
    public: const decltype(X)& get_##X() const { return X; } \ 
            void set_##X(const decltype(X)& value) { X = value; } private:
```

**Utility**:

```
class Sph
{
   ...
private:
  float GET_SET(Radius);
  float GET_SET(Segments);
  ...
};
```

**Usage**:

```
Sph sph;
sph.set_Radius(3.3);
cout << sph.get_Radius() << "\n";
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/SpDE9G).

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
class Sph {
  /* ... */
public:
  template<typename ParamType, typename... Extras> void SetParam(ParamType, Extras...);
  /* ... */
};

template<> inline void Sph::SetParam(float radius) {
  Radius = radius;
}

template<> inline void Sph::SetParam(float segments,
    bool ignored_dummy_argument_to_distinguish_between_two_overloads)
{
  Segments = segments;
}

template<> inline void Sph::SetParam(bool inited) {
  isInited = inited;
}
```

Comment: if i have more than two overloads how do i handle that situation.